# Progressive AES decryption with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I try to use progressive ciphering from CryptoJS to decrypt files.
The files are encrypted & base64 encoded with OpenSSL as shown in the CryptoJS documentation ([CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)).

When I use CryptoJS.AES.decrypt everything works fine:

```
var encryptedText = "U2FsdGVkX19X2wD+xFnLd3WLuzW5qA0dppGtV+VPOFdjslLsZpwfdqd02BOe4pvxG2zZok06DchVfZBBBS/JWg==";

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("A6420198998C341308AF100CF7CCAC95884E4084581A4F8CFB8DFA7FEAD045EF");
var iv =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("7F418B4532F8BC83261639DBA60C0A50");

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedText, key, {iv: iv});
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(decrypted);
var result = atob(base64);
```

But when I try progressive decryption the result is corrupted:

```
var decrypted;
var cipher = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createDecryptor(key, { iv: iv});
decrypted = cipher.process(encryptedText);
decrypted.concat(cipher.finalize());
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(decrypted);
var result = atob(base64);
```

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `encryptedText` is a string which is OpenSSL formatted. It is not the pure ciphertext which you get from the `ciphertext` property after encryption:

```
var ct = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {iv: iv}).ciphertext;
```

The `Cipher.process` function [only accepts a `WordArray` or the data string](https://github.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/tree/3.1.2/src/cipher-core.js#L110) and `encryptedText` is neither. You either need to use [`CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL.parse()`](https://github.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/tree/3.1.2/src/cipher-core.js#L597) to retrieve the ciphertext `WordArray`:

```
var ct = CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL.parse(encryptedText).ciphertext;
```

or directly retrieve `ciphertext` when you encrypt it like in the first snippet.

After that, you can do:

```
var decrypted = cipher.process(ct);
decrypted = decrypted.concat(cipher.finalize());
```

I'm also not sure why you stringify as Base64 and then use `atob`, because there is an easier way to get the original string back:

```
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```